# Checkbox click of input. Checkbox of other posts is selected

Tags: css

I put a check box on the input function to make a secret comment on one post and put a secret comment function.
The first post was applied without any problem, but the problem is that when I put a secret comment on the second post and click on the check box, the first check box is selected. If you click on the check box of the third post, the check box of the first post is selected. And I think it's a check box problem, but how do we solve this problem?

I didn't seem to explain well, so I brought it to the picture to see what my post looked like....;D

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZn3R.jpg

```
    <form action="#">
                <p class="secretWrap">  
                    <label for="secret">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="secret" class="checkbox" name="secret" />
                            <span>SECRET</span>
                    </label>
                </p>
            </form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4wd56t7a/

Comment: can you show your JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using the same 'id' and 'for' attributes on both of your checkboxes. They need to be unique or else you're associating that label with the first instance of the id.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label